# npm install -g while also updating package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, virtualenv, nodeenv

Yes, I know, `npm install -g` isn't supposed to update `package.json`. But I need something that will have a similar effect.

My problem is as follows:
I want to keep everything separate, so I would like to install node, npm, and every package in a virtual environment.
I do this by running:

1. `$ python -m venv <venv_name>`
2. `$ <venv_name>\scripts\activate`
3. `$ pip install nodeenv`
4. `$ nodeenv -p`

These four steps download nodejs and npm in a virtual environment.

The issue I'm having is that whenever I want to install a nodejs package via npm I have to install it 'globally' in the virtual environment otherwise it doesn't work.
To illustrate this, I will show you what happens when I install a package using normally with:

`$ npm install express`

or

`$ npm install nodmeon`

This will save nodemon or express in dependencies, however it wont recognize them as commands, for example:

`$ nodemon run start` will return `'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

But this wont happen when I install packages with `npm install -g`. They work just fine when I do that, but the problem is that they wont save in `package.json`.

What I've been doing is installing things 2 times, one globally and one normally just so it can be saved in package.json.

My question is: Is there anyway for my global installations to be outputted in package.json? Or is there any way you would recommend me to solve this problem?

Comment: put nodemon in a [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts/) in package.json then it will work. Its normal for it not to work unless they are global

Comment: You can use npx

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it was normal not to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the packages cli even if it is not installed globally. like nodemon, knex etc.

if you are using `npm`, you can use `npx`

```
npx nodemon
```

if you are using `yarn`, you can use `yarn`

```
yarn nodemon
```

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2018/04/05/npx-the-npm-package-runner.html

> npx is a tool for running npm packages that: live inside of a local node_modules folder or are not installed globally.